# WSDL explorer/viewer for Linux / Ubuntu (gui)

Tags: linux, web-services, xsd, wsdl

Is there a GUI tool that can display details about a *WSDL file* and XSD files?

Maybe a WSDL editor is also an option. My needs are mainly **inspecting** the structure and options I have to call a service.
Preferably a bit more **graphical** than just reading the XML files themselves.

I tried **Eclipse WSDL editor**, which can be very useful, but I'm having trouble with that one. So, is there **a comparable alternative**? (otherwise I need to go fixing the Eclipse tool...)

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use http://www.soapui.org/. It's free and open source. Also you can pro version with commercial support. But free version is enough for me.

Comment: On Ubuntu: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/web;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install soapui;